# Laravel installed but when compiled cannot locate page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I installed laravel using composer and created an application using command line. I then opened the application in NetBeans and I pointed the IDE to the index.php file then I ran it, which takes me to http://localhost/public/index.php then it says object not found.

XAMPP is running as I can navigate to the welcome page for XAMPP.

I cannot understand why it is not locating the index file. I know usually you get the Laravel page when you compile and it is successful

Answer (score 1):

You must configure XAMPP, because you have wrong web server configuration. Point web server to a `public` directory, not root one. Then restart web server.